# Embarcadero C++ XE5 and native Android/IOs support

Tags: c++builder

Will C++ XE5 alone (not Delphi) work with Android and iOS?
I can't read any info about this specific question on the net.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is information that is available from the vendor web site at [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com), and if not found there should be addressed to the vendor's Sales Department via email.

Comment: This also might help: [C++ Builder XE5 Feature Matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/cbuilder-feature-matrix.pdf) - note it's a PDF file. It clearly indicates no support yet for iOS or Android in C++ Builder.

Comment: Estimated winter 2013: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/42544/thumb03000005.png

Answer (score 1):

Not at present, but planned for later this year.

Here is their roadmap:  http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42544

UPDATE:  C++ Builder XE6, released in April 2014, has native Android/iOS support

Answer (score 1):

Planned for later 2014 in the 2014 Roadmap.
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43677

Answer (score 0):

XE5 supports Win32, Win64 and OSX. iOS and Android are in development, planned winter 2013. Linux, and other OSs to follow.